# Ckeditor Image Dialog Windows customizations - set default values

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to customization image dialog window for ckeditor 4 giving "hasCaption" field to be checked by default, to have captioned images alwyas.
[image]

I tried ev.data.hasCaption = "1"; ev.data.hasCaption = "on";
  But no luck

Answer (score 0):

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
   if (ev.data.name == 'image') {
       dialogDefinition.dialog.on('show', function(e){
            var imgElement = editor.getSelection().getStartElement();
            var dialogBox = e.sender;
            //I am not sure about setvalue works for checkbox or not
            //may be you can try checked()
            dialogBox.getContentElement('info','hasCaption').setValue(1);
       });
   }
});
```

You just need to find proper CKEDITORS image plugins method to tick the checkbox. If my setValue do not work.